# Passar valores de uma classe ao gerar um pdf em JavaFX

Tags: java, pdf, javafx

Boa tarde, criei um PDF.java, que tem como função gerar um pdf, e em outro arquivo(FormularioHoteleriosController.java) ao clicar em um determinado botão, eu instancio o arquivo PDF.java para poder gerar e abrir o pdf, porém, eu necessito que quando eu clicar no botão que encontra-se no FormularioHoteleriosControler.java, resgate valores de EditText's localizados no mesmo, e então, imprimir os resultados no PDF. Obrigado!!

ARQUIVO QUE GERA O PDF:

```
public class Pdf {
public static final String IMAGE = "imagens/boleto.png";
public static final String DEST = "results/images/boleto.pdf";

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, DocumentException {
    File file = new File(DEST);
    file.getParentFile().mkdirs();
    new Pdf().createPdf(DEST);
}
public void createPdf(String dest) throws IOException, DocumentException {
    Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4.rotate());
    PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(dest));
    document.open();

    PdfContentByte canvas = writer.getDirectContentUnder();
    Image image = Image.getInstance(IMAGE);
    image.scaleAbsolute(PageSize.A4.rotate());
    image.setAbsolutePosition(0, 0);
    canvas.addImage(image);
    document.close();

    Desktop.getDesktop().open(new File("results/images/boleto.pdf"));
}
```

}

ARQUIVO QUE CHAMA INSTANCIA O PDF.AJVA AO CLICAR NO BOTÃO:

```
@FXML public void gerarPdf(){

    try {
        Pdf.main(null);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (DocumentException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}
```

Comment: Sua pergunta está confusa, mais uma coisa me confunde mais ainda: seu código tem duas classes com main?? Porque o JavaFX cria uma Classe main e um Controlador.

Comment: olá Gustavo, eu não entendi sua observação, duas classes com main?

Comment: Estou tentando resgatar valores preenchidos em um EditText, localizado no arquivo que instancia o pdf para ser gerado. E então, apresentá-los no pdf gerado.

Comment: Sua classe PDF tem um public static void main(String[] args) e a classe do principal do javafx tem outra public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

Comment: Entendi, mas isso impedi que eu consiga realizar o esclarecido?

Comment: Do ponto de vista da programação é incorreto.

Answer (score 1):

Sugiro que você crie uma [janela modal](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/stage/Modality.html) para exibir seu PDF. Primeiro vamos corrigir sua classe de geração de PDF seguindo as boas práticas de programação em Java:

```
public class GeradorPdf {

    private String source;
    private String destination;

    // Construtor da Classe
    public GeradorPdf(String source, String destination) {
        this.source = source;
        this.destination = destination;
    }

    // Não mexi neste método mas você poderia retornar a Image gerada
    // para uma classe VisualizadorPdf
    public void createPdf() throws IOException, DocumentException {
        Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4.rotate());
        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(destination));
        document.open();

        PdfContentByte canvas = writer.getDirectContentUnder();
        Image image = Image.getInstance(source);
        image.scaleAbsolute(PageSize.A4.rotate());
        image.setAbsolutePosition(0, 0);
        canvas.addImage(image);
        document.close();

        Desktop.getDesktop().open(new File("results/images/boleto.pdf"));
   }

   // Encapsulamento dos atributos
   public String getSource(){
       return this.source;
   }

   public String getDestination(){
       return this.destination;
   }

   public void setSource(String newSource){
       this.source = newSource;
   }

   public void setDestination(String newDestination){
       this.destination = newDestination;
   }
```

Agora vou mostrar como se cria uma janela modal em JavaFX usando o FXML. Primeiramente vamos ter que criar uma variável global para seu Stage no método `start` da sua classe principal:

```
public static Stage stage;

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("FXMLDocument.fxml"));

    Scene scene = new Scene(root);
    stage = primaryStage;
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
}
```

Agora a classe VisualizadorPdf (Janela Modal):

```
public class VisualizadorPdf {

    private final Stage dialog;
    private final Image image;
    // O resto de seus atributos (botões, paineis, etc);

    public VisualizadorPdf(Stage owner, Image image){
        this.image = image;

        dialog = new Stage();
        dialog.initModality(Modality.WINDOW_MODAL);
        dialog.initOwner(owner);
        dialog.setScene(createScene());
        dialog.setTitle("Título da minha janela");
    }

    public Scene createScene() {
        // Crie sua cena aqui
    }

    // Método para exibir sua janela
    public void show() {
        dialog.show();
    }
}
```

Se estiver sem ideias de como criar uma scene pode olhar este [visualizador de pdf](https://github.com/gbfragoso/JasperViewerFX/blob/master/src/org/fxutils/viewer/JasperViewerFX.java). Seria interessante passar a imagem do Gerador para o Visualizador, ou você pode unir os dois em uma classe só, isso depende de você.

Por fim o uso seria dessa forma:

```
@FXML
private TextField meutextfield;

// ...

@FXML 
public void gerarPdf(){

    try {

        // Pegando valores dos TextField
        String valor = meutextfield.getText();

        GeradorPdf gerador = new GeradorPdf("imagens/boleto.png", "results/images/boleto.pdf");
        Image image = gerador.createPdf(); // Supondo que seguiu minha sugestão
        VisualizadorPdf visualizador = new VisualizadorPdf(SuaClasse.stage, image);
        visualizador.show();

    } catch (IOException | DocumentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
}
```